# giving errors in bootstrap when try to use breadcrumbs in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

hi i want to use a breadcrumb for my zend framework application

i craeted navigation.xml in configs folder where application.ini is .

and in the bootstarp i added following code

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml');

    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

and in the layout i  added folllowing code

```
    <div id="menu">
        <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        You are in: <?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render(); ?>
    </div>
```

it is not working , errors are given

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Navigation_Exception' with message 'Invalid argument: Unable to determine class to instantiate' in /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Navigation/Page.php:223 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Navigation/Container.php(117): Zend_Navigation_Page::factory(Array) 
#1 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Navigation/Container.php(164): Zend_Navigation_Container->addPage(Array) 
#2 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Navigation.php(46): Zend_Navigation_Container->addPages(Object(Zend_Config_Xml)) 
#3 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/application/Bootstrap.php(94): Zend_Navigation->__construct(Object(Zend_Config_Xml)) 
#4 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(666): Bootstrap->_initNavigation() 
#5 /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(619): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('navigati in /home/kanishka/workspace/jetwing_ibe/library/Zend/Navigation/Page.php on line 223
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <nav>
        <dashboard>
            <label>dashboard</label>
            <controller>dashboard</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>dashboard</resource>  
            <pages>
                <rates>
                    <label>Rates</label>
                    <controller>rates</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <pages>
                        <index>
                            <label>index</label>
                            <controller>rates</controller>
                            <action>index</action>
                            <class>dontdisplay</class>
                        </index>                
                    </pages>
                </rates>
                <occupancydenomination>
                    <label>Occupancydenominations</label>
                    <controller>occupancydenomination</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <pages>
                        <index>
                            <label>Occupancydenomination</label>
                            <controller>occupancydenomination</controller>
                            <action>index</action>
                            <class>dontdisplay</class>
                        </index>
                        <add>
                            <label>Add Occupancydenomination</label>
                            <controller>occupancydenomination</controller>
                            <action>add</action>
                            <class>dontdisplay</class>
                        </add>
                    </pages>
                </occupancydenomination>
            </pages>        
        </dashboard>
    </nav>
</config>
```

i am not sure what the error is . please help me ................

Comment: Post the contents of navigation.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to your config file.

You're not providing enough parameters for the navigation container to determine the correct page type, `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` or `Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri`.

Also, you know there's a [navigation resource plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.navigation), right?

**UPDATE**

Get rid of the `<nav>` wrapper element. It's trying to interpret that as a page.

That or do follow the [example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html#zend.navigation.containers.creating) and specify the config section correctly

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('/path/to/navigation.xml', 'nav');
$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
```

Comment: i searched in web , but couldn't find a way to do this . please show me how to provide those paramaeters :(

Comment: mmmmmmmmmm added an extra parameter my previous code was Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml');  now i changed it to Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml','nav');  now the exeption is not given , but still breadcrumbs not working properly , still continuing :)

Comment: @tittletipz You could start by posting an example of your config XML file

Comment: In my opinion, the Navigation Resource plugin is crap. It clutters the application config. I prefer a separate navigation.xml (https://github.com/leek/zf-components/blob/master/library/Leek/View/Helper/Navigation/Config.php)

Comment: mmmm i figure out an issue , the case is i am not in the default module , there is a module called admin in my site where should i add that in my .xml

Comment: @leek fair enough, though given a small enough navigation, it's more efficient to add it into to the app config to avoid the overhead of another `Zend_Config` instance